# ¿Cómo se analiza sintacticamente la frase "Mi nombre Pablo se dice"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Esta frase me trae muchas confusiones:

> Mi nombre Pablo se dice.

¿Cómo se analiza sintácticamente?

Se puede escribir también como:

> Pablo se dice mi nombre.
>
> Mi nombre se dice Pablo.

¿Cuál es el sujeto en esta frase? ¿Y que es "se"?.

¿Es en análisis sintáctico el mismo en todas las distintas frases? ¿Hay un objeto directo en alguna o en todas?

Comment: Pablo, ¿quién te dio esta frase?  Se oye muy rara.  ¿Estás tratando de expresar la siguiente idea, acaso? *Yo me llamo Paul.  En español, "Paul" se expresa como "Pablo."*  O bien: *En español, "Paul" quiere decir "Pablo."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La frase en sí es bastante curiosa, pero ya que la pregunta habla solamente de sintaxis, me limitaré a la sintaxis.

Como ocurre con la mayoría de las oraciones en español, es posible intercambiar de lugar sus partes sin que el significado cambie. Sin embargo, algunos órdenes son comunes, otros sólo se usan para enfatizar alguna parte, y otros son realmente raros.

El patrón normal aquí sería *Mi nombre se dice Pablo.* En cualquier otro orden la oración suena muy extraña, aunque podría aparecer de esa manera si la métrica lo requiere (en una canción, en un poema, en un refrán). El sujeto es *mi nombre* y el objeto directo es *Pablo*, sin importar en qué orden esté la frase.

Por lo que entiendo del asunto, *se dice* es una forma **pasiva refleja**. El verbo en infinitivo, *decirse*, funciona como *ser dicho*, con el significado de *ser expresado como*, *ser puesto en palabras como*, etc.

Sobre el uso de *se* es conveniente consultar el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs) (para el uso como indicador de la pasiva refleja, ver la sección *2.1 b*).

Comment: A menos que Pablo esté expresando a sí mismo el nombre que poseo yo (otra posibilidad para esta frase rara), en tal caso, el orden canónico sería Pablo se dice mi nombre.